# Eloquent model boot events never triggered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I can't get model boot events to work. This is the most basic Eloquent functionality, so I am sure this is probably something simple I'm screwing up here.

When I run this code:

```
User::create(['email'=>'test@example.com']);
```

Or this code:

```
(new User)->fill(['email'=>'test@example.com'])->save();
```

Then I expect the `saving` event method to be triggered in the model, but it never is:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasImage;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function (User $user) {
            dd('user saving is never triggered');
        });
    }
}
```

Yes, this is exactly the code I am using. Doesn't get more basic than this.

Model traits also don't execute their boot events if I add them but the `bootHasImage` is still called:

```
trait HasImage
{
    protected static function bootHasImage()
    {
        dd('this will be hit on boot');

        static::saved(function (self $model) {
            dd('this is never hit on model save');
        });
    }
}
```

To get that trait `saved` event to work, I have to also move it directly to the `UserObserver`.

What could be going on here?

Comment: The method might have changed in v7, because according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events-using-closures), the method should be called `booted`.

Comment: Changing to `booted` gets code within there to execute, however, the events are still never called when the model saves or creates.

Comment: I've not used Laravel for a few years. Do you need to extend the `Model` class for the events to work?

Comment: `Authenticatable` (`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`) extends `Model`

Comment: The only way I can get model events to work is if I bind them in a separate observer class (e.g. `UserObserver`). However, boot methods on traits for models still don't work. For instance, if I have trait `HasImage` on the `User` model, then the `bootHasImage()` static method never gets called on boot. This always worked in earlier versions of Laravel and looking at the boot code that Laravel uses suggests it still should in v7.0. I'm miffed as to what's going on here.

Comment: @eComEvo Note that there is [difference between `saving` and `saved`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php#L240-L260) point in time of when event is being invoked. In your question you've used those interchangeably unintentionally or by mistake.

Comment: i have tested your code on my laravel (v5.7) it works just fine, strange

Comment: @OMR yeah works just fine for me in v6 and under as well. Super bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

Remeber to set on your User model the $fillable option if you want to use mass assignable property.

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'email'       
    ];
```

Comment: `$guarded = []` takes care of this.